# zsh: command not found: virtualenv

Tags: django, macos, virtualenv

I am trying to install virtualenv on Mac Terminal for Django but its showing me - zsh: command not found: virtualenv and i also tried following command

@macbook-air trydjango % virtualenv-p python3 .

zsh: command not found: virtualenv -p

@macbook-air trydjango % pip install virtualenv

zsh: command not found: pip

I also tried to run the commands ad per this article https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac#what-to-do

$ brew install pyenv

but not working

How can i install this.

I have no idea where to begin researching this.

Comment: Python2 is past end of life and does not come installed by default on most platforms including current macos. Use pip3 or if you really need python2, install it with something like homebrew: `brew install python@2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing in the right directory with this command:
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install virtualenv

Also check this link for other variants to solve the problem:
https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-command-not-found-error-on-virtualenv/